# Android SpeechRecognizer not working. Language pack issue?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

The SpeechRecognizer portion of our app "ConverStory" has all of a sudden stopped working on some devices recently.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.converstory.  We use the speech to text portion to run searches.  As soon as the app starts it throws up the error "Speech Recognition Failed".  I'm hoping I can get some direction.  I'm the producer of the app and we just switched development teams who aren't familiar with the meat and potatoes of the code so I'd like to glean as much information as I can here before I approach them with the issue(s).

I just searched for "speech" in the Android Studio logcat which shows (and I apologize for the formatting):

> 2023-08-08 14:28:47.793 30728-30728/? V/SpeechRecognition: Start
> Listening
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.000 30728-30728/? V/SpeechRecognition: Health
> Check: Healthy.
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.000 30728-30728/? V/SpeechRecognition: Broadcast
> receive: android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.023 9630-9630/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Offline
> recognizer - start listening
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.024 9630-9630/?
> I/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Initialize Soda [locale: en-US],
> [applicationDomain: AMBIENT_ONESHOT]
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.030 9630-9680/? E/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Failed to
> get language pack of required locale: error 13
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.034 9630-9680/? W/RecognitionServiceImpl: Speech
> recognition error type LANGUAGE_PACK_ERROR with error code 13
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.064 30728-30728/? E/SpeechRecognition: on error:
> 13
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.118 30728-30728/? V/SpeechRecognition: Unregister
> audio switch receiver.
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.122 30728-30728/? E/SpeechRecognizer: not
> connected to the recognition service
>
> 2023-08-08 14:28:48.122 30728-30728/? E/SpeechRecognizer: not
> connected to the recognition service

This happens on a Samsung Galaxy A21S (Android 12), a Samsung Galaxy Z Fold3 5G (Android 13) and a couple of other modern devices.  Obviously some issue with the language pack.  I even tried updating en-US language in Assistant settings.  It used to work fine so I'm puzzled about what might have changed.

On the working devices, searching "speech" in the logcat shows the following:

> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.162 18222-18222/? V/SpeechRecognition: Start
> Listening
>
> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.372 18222-18222/? V/SpeechRecognition: Health
> Check: Healthy.
>
> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.440 24405-24405/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Offline
> recognizer - start listening
>
> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.440 24405-24405/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer:
> Initialize Soda [locale: en-US], [applicationDomain: AMBIENT_ONESHOT]
>
> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.450 24405-24431/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer:
> Initialize Soda with language pack directory
>
> 2023-08-09 15:37:06.658 24405-24431/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Offline
> recognizer - start detection

...and off it goes and starts working.

This is on a Pixel 5 (Android 13).  LG V30 (Android 12) and a Nexus 6P (Android 8.1.1).  Also I'd like to point out that the working phones also show the "E/SpeechRecognizer: not connected to the recognition service" error but it doesn't seem to affect the speech recognition.  I assume that's for the online service?  I can't say for certain but I seem to recall that with the previous developer we decided to go with the on device (offline) service as there were advantages to that.

Furthermore I just received an AdMob Must Fix for "Site Behavior: Navigation" which I'm sure is related to this.  Ads are still being served on the devices that work but I'm sure that it's just a matter of time before that stops.

Any advice or insight is appreciated.  The app is actually really cool when it is working.  It streams images (nouns) about what you're talking about along with captions in over 50 languages.  I would be grateful even if you could check it out and let me know if it's working for you or not.  Thank you very much.

Like I said this just started happened out of the blue.   It's been working just fine for the past couple of years.  It certainly has something to do with the "Failed to get language pack of required locale: error 13".